# VpnService Android 4.0

Tags: android, vpn, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Please i need an example of using VpnService in Android 4.0 with PPTP VPN Server.
I'm tried ToyVpnService but it's not using a username & passwd to connect to VPN server.

Comment: I would wait and upgrade to Android 4.1 as the VPN source code had a bug in it that made it almost worthless to try and code with some VPN services.  http://www.securitykiss.com/resources/articles/android_vpn_bug/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VPNService API is not for configuring the system VPN Services but for implementing your own VPN solution. You can for example implement protocols that are not implemented by the system like OpenVPN.

To use pptp with the VPNService API you need to implement the PPTP protocol yourself (or port an existing implementation (should not be difficult))

Comment: A porting guide is too much for stackoverflow. If you a good understanding of networking, tun device and programming experience it should be relativity straight forward.

Comment: I'm reverse engineering the app Hideman - will post my final result when I'm done...

Comment: That is probably not necessary as it is based on the "OpenVPN for Android" app.